# Connect Wireless router to Ethernet router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

I have two router, wireless and ethernet router.
Wireless router is TP-Link WA501G and ethernet router is PTI-8411 Annex A.
Can I connect LAN cable from Wireless router to any of LAN ports (http://www.automation-drive.com/EX/05-13-23/Ethernet-router.gif to any of that four) on Ethernet router and so share internet connection ?

Thanks, and sorry for bad grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple yes.

But you must point your make your gateway address the device that plugs into the internet and to keep it simple, keep the IP address subnet the same.

so...

Ethernet router (internet access) 192.168.1.1 
wireless router 192.168.1.2

your ip address: 
IP: 192.168.1.3 
SM: 255.255.255.0 
GW: 192.168.1.1 
DNS: 192.168.1.1

This can be either assigned staticly or via DHCP.

On another note (DHCP Server):

1.) If the internet router is the DHCP Server then you just need to change the IP scope to start  after the wireless router IP.

2.) If the Wireless router is the DHCP server
- Make sure the Gateway a 192.1681.1 (Internal Modem IP)
- Make sure the DNS 192.168.1.1 (Internal Modem IP)

Answer (score 2):

That will certainly work, but make sure you disable DHCP on the wireless router and set the gateway to the first router's IP

Comment: This is not necessary depending how your DHCP is setup. You can point your DHCP server to auto assign the Gw and DNS and that depends again on which device is acting as the DHCP server.